# URL Convert xml string from an API and parse into an array - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, uri

I have been trying for two days to figure this out and can't get what I am doing wrong. I have been working with APIs for a while now, but this is the first time I have tried it with Ruby.

Currently this what I have:

```
require 'httparty'    

response = URI.parse('http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area(55423,20))?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
parse = CGI.parse(response.query)

result = parse['id'].first  

$result = result
```

I plan to move $result to result.html.erb to iterate into a table, but not sure if I have the parsing done correctly, since I can't view the contents of reponse or $result. Any idea if I am even close? and how to iterate through the xml after..

Comment: Shouldn't you look at `response.body` instead of `response.query`?

Comment: For parsing you can use http://www.nokogiri.org

Comment: I have been trying to figure out Nokogiri as well. Sometimes it isn't such a great thing when you have so many options, as in Nokogiri. Just want to pull the XML data, parse it into a useable array that I can iterate into an html table.

Comment: It is not supposed to be that difficult: `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.threescompany.com/"))`

Comment: I was more focused on the problem, than a key. I made it more 'anon' thanks. I'll give that a shot with Noko.